# Validate Given MS Argument

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to know a way to check if a given string in `ms()` is correctly formatted and not an invalid time.

```
const ms = require('ms')
const str = 'abc'

setTimeout(function(){

   //Do something

}, ms(str))
```

The goal is to detect an whether `str` is valid or invalid MS time before the function timeout starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source](https://github.com/vercel/ms/blob/master/tests.js#L57), `NaN` is returned for an invalid argument. So you could do:

```
const ms = require('ms');
const str = 'abc';
const msVal = ms(str);
if (!isNaN(msVal)) {
    setTimeout(() => {    
        //Do something    
    }, msVal);
} else {
    // handle invalid format
}
```